# How to scan image taken by camera intent to update gallery in android

Tags: android

I have this code in my app but it doesn't seem to be working.  Only after restarting my phone then all the images are displayed in the gallery.  No i am wondering is there a way to do this as soon as the photo is taken and then update the gallery without the need to restart the phone.

this is what i have:

```
protected void mediaScan() {
  sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                 + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))));
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: WHY??????????????????

Comment: You cant anymore do this in kk and above.

Comment: Then why the down vote? why not just say so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its static `scanFile()` method:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { yourPath }, null, null);
```

Comment: @k0sh: It should work on all Android versions, API Level 8+. `MediaScannerConnection` itself should work on all versions of Android; the static edition of `scanFile()` was only added in API Level 8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had an issue with sending the broadcast scanner awhile ago that i had to remove it from one of my apps and i never knew about such method exists. Thanks for the response and the answer

Comment: @ElefantPhace well its not a shame to ask and confirm ;)